card component ignores column size
I am using bulma 1.0 and I tried to get an example working:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@1.0.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="randomUIDNumber" class="content-tab" style="display:block">
    <div class="columns is-multiline mt-3">
        <div className="column is-one-third mr-3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-image">
                <figure class="image is-4by3">
                  <img
                    src="https://bulma.io/assets/images/placeholders/1280x960.png"
                    alt="Placeholder image"
                  />
                </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <figure class="image is-48x48">
                      <img
                        src="https://bulma.io/assets/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                        alt="Placeholder image"
                      />
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-content">
                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                    <p class="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec
                  iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>. <a href="#">#css</a>
                  <a href="#">#responsive</a>
                  <br />
                  <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>       
            
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-image">
                <figure class="image is-4by3">
                  <img
                    src="https://bulma.io/assets/images/placeholders/1280x960.png"
                    alt="Placeholder image"
                  />
                </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <figure class="image is-48x48">
                      <img
                        src="https://bulma.io/assets/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                        alt="Placeholder image"
                      />
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-content">
                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                    <p class="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec
                  iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>. <a href="#">#css</a>
                  <a href="#">#responsive</a>
                  <br />
                  <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-image">
                <figure class="image is-4by3">
                  <img
                    src="https://bulma.io/assets/images/placeholders/1280x960.png"
                    alt="Placeholder image"
                  />
                </figure>
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                    <figure class="image is-48x48">
                      <img
                        src="https://bulma.io/assets/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                        alt="Placeholder image"
                      />
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-content">
                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                    <p class="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec
                  iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>. <a href="#">#css</a>
                  <a href="#">#responsive</a>
                  <br />
                  <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
               
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>



This places 3 x the example from the bulma.io page in 3 rows - but not all three in one row. I want to place the cards next to each other with maybe mr-3 attribute for some space.
